# How to divide a number field and round it to 2 decimal places in Crystal reports?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a value say 12345678. I need to divide this by 1000 and the result should be 12345.68.
How to achieve this Crystal reports?
Here's what I tried: Round({value1} / 1000, 2)

Comment: Is your CR object formatted to Number. Even if you calculate it through formula it will still show as whole number if you didn't set the format on object inside CR designer

Comment: Ahh yes @AnelHodžić u are right. Its formatted to Number.

Comment: If this solved your question I can post it as an answer if you agree , so other may find it useful ? @DevSa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not enough to just format inside formula field.  You need to set object Format to Number and set its precision.

[image: Format like this]

Answer (score 1):

The expression `Round(12345678 / 1000, 2)` in Crystal returns 12,345.68

Please clarify: in what way the result you get is not what you want?

Comment: Value has been formatted to type Number, so it is displayed as a Whole number.  In my case the output I'm seeing is : 12346